# Discard Draft should clear the "Answer your own question" checkbox

Tags: bug, status-completed, draft

This is a super minor issue.

If I have a draft that has the "Answer Your Own Question" checkbox checked, then (in my opinion), selecting "discard" should clear that checkbox.

If this is by design, then sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.